# To print an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

please help lead to the title of the json-array
 
my attempt:

```
(function (jQuery){
    var json = {
        "news": [{
            "img": "http://static3.www.net/img/300x300/2257740.jpeg",
            "title": "qwerty1",
            "url": "http://news.net.www.ru/newdata/adclick?ad=674134&bl=80802&ct=adpreview&st=16&in=YK2NFgCJu2FWSQoAjkkKAIhJCgBhSQoAfkkKAGJJCgA%3D&ag=19",
            "id": "674134"
        }, {
            "img": "http://static5.www.net/img/300x300/2257778.jpeg",
            "title": "qwerty2",
            "url": "http://news.net.www.ru/newdata/adclick?ad=674190&bl=80802&ct=adpreview&st=16&in=YK2NFgCJu2FWSQoAjkkKAIhJCgBhSQoAfkkKAGJJCgA%3D&ag=19",
            "id": "674190"
        }, {
            "img": "http://static3.www.net/img/300x300/2257776.jpeg",
            "title": "qwerty3",
            "url": "http://news.net.www.ru/newdata/adclick?ad=674184&bl=80802&ct=adpreview&st=16&in=YK2NFgCJu2FWSQoAjkkKAIhJCgBhSQoAfkkKAGJJCgA%3D&ag=19",
            "id": "674184"
        }, {
            "img": "http://static2.www.net/img/300x300/2257748.jpeg",
            "title": "qwerty4",
            "url": "http://news.net.www.ru/newdata/adclick?ad=674145&bl=80802&ct=adpreview&st=16&in=YK2NFgCJu2FWSQoAjkkKAIhJCgBhSQoAfkkKAGJJCgA%3D&ag=19",
            "id": "674145"
        }, {
            "img": "http://static1.www.net/img/300x300/2257766.jpeg",
            "title": "qwerty5",
            "url": "http://news.net.www.ru/newdata/adclick?ad=674174&bl=80802&ct=adpreview&st=16&in=YK2NFgCJu2FWSQoAjkkKAIhJCgBhSQoAfkkKAGJJCgA%3D&ag=19",
            "id": "674174"
        }, {
            "img": "http://static3.www.net/img/300x300/2257750.jpeg",
            "title": "qwerty6",
            "url": "http://news.net.www.ru/newdata/adclick?ad=674146&bl=80802&ct=adpreview&st=16&in=YK2NFgCJu2FWSQoAjkkKAIhJCgBhSQoAfkkKAGJJCgA%3D&ag=19",
            "id": "674146"
        }]
    }

    //console.log(JSON.parse(json));

    jQuery.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {
       alert(idx + '__' + obj.news.title);
    });
})($);
```

As a result, the console displays the following error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

you can see the online version of the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8dwjbj9/2/)

Comment: 1. You are missing a `;` after your closing `}` on the object. 2. You dont need to parse this json because its already an object so thats going to be an issue. http://jsfiddle.net/x8dwjbj9/6/

Comment: `JSON.parse` converts string to object, `JSON.stringify` converts object to string. You are trying to convert object to object with function expecting string as input.

Comment: Your `json` variable is a JavaScript object.  It's ***not*** JSON.  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: use CTRL+P, when open a window you select how many pages you can print and click OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last bit to -

```
    jQuery.each(json.news, function(idx, obj) {
           alert(idx + '__' + obj['title']);
        });
    })($);
```

You have to iterate news of json

Answer (score 0):

It is already parsed. So `JSON.parse` will throw an error. The fix is `JSON.parse(json)` should be simple `json`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you should add `if(json.hasOwnProperty(i))`

Comment: @JanLegner Sorry, actually $.each supports object iteration too. I missed that. So I removed that line.